# How can I see in Netbeans, which methods an object knows?

Tags: php, netbeans

I'm using NetBeans and PHP. For example, I insert this code:

```
<?php
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
    foreach($dbh->query('SELECT * from FOO') as $row) {
        print_r($row);
    }
    $dbh = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
?>
```

Now, when I hover my mouse over the $dbh symbol, I get no information about it. Other IDEs tell me which methods an object understands. I'm sure NetBeans can do the same. How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write `$dbh->` and a list of functions should come up automatically. If not, press  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>

Also, [see this about helping netbeans with function](http://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/code_completion_for_a_class) return types and class members.

Comment: The key combo would be CMD-Space on the Mac version of Netbeans.

Comment: how bad, this is reserved by spotlight already. Hope that can be changed??

Answer (score 0):

You can also edit the settings for the Code Completion feature in the `Editor->Code Completion` section of the Options window. You can modify how/when the list pops up.